# Windows 8 requesting duplicate updates

Tags: windows, windows-8, security, updates

Am I not alone when it comes to Windows requesting "...Flash Player for Windows 8 for x64..." multiple times even after updated, along with a few other security update duplicates. Is there a fix so I know I am not having a security issue?

This is a windows 8 upgrade from 7, the one they offered for $40.

```
Update for Internet Explorer Flash Player for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2819372)

Download size: 24 KB

You may need to restart your computer for this update to take effect.

Update type: Important

This update addresses the vulnerability discussed in Microsoft Security Advisory (KB2819372). Security issues have been identified that could allow an attacker to compromise a computer running Internet Explorer Flash Player for Windows 8 and gain control over it. You can help protect your computer by installing this update from Microsoft. After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.

More information: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=264959

Help and Support: 
http://support.microsoft.com
```

Comment: This is not a problem I have seen on my system, is there something that specifically causes this?

Comment: Not sure, I do have Ubuntu in dual boot and recently upgraded that OS, but they are on separate hard-drives. It is a Dell Precision 6100 workstation/laptop and have noticed a few glitches in getting the headphones and disk drive working in the Windows 8 only. In Ubuntu they work fine.

Comment: @Karan that link is for 7? "We're sorry, but your operating system is not supported by Microsoft Fix it at this time."

Comment: This is the other one... Definition Update for Windows Defender - KB2267602 (Definition 1.151.2286.0)

Download size: 382 KB

Update type: Important

Install this update to revise the definition files that are used to detect viruses, spyware, and other potentially unwanted software. Once you have installed this item, it cannot be removed.

More information: 
http://www.microsoft.com/athome/security/spyware/software/about/overview.mspx

Help and Support: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=52661

Comment: Try [this one](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=260622) instead, should run on Win8. Also see [Windows Update or Microsoft Update repeatedly offers the same update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339).

Comment: @Karan Well, some changes happened and it asked for a restart, but the Flash Player issue still arises on update.

Comment: The official suggestion seems to be: "If you keep seeing the same update being offered for installation, try to install the update at a later time. If after installation you see the update being offered again, post your issue to the Microsoft Communities for resolution about this specific update."

Comment: For the Flash Player update I suggest removing it from your system, rebooting, then reinstalling from the Adobe site.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Where would the OP find a Flash plugin for Win8 on Adobe's site?

Comment: @karan. Aha, missed that "Flash Player is integrated with Internet Explorer in Windows 8. It's unnecessary to install Flash Player".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you've installed the Flash Debugger update `KB2777262`.

Install the latest Version of the debugger which includes the latest Flash Security Update:

32Bit: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=269535

64Bit: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=269538